# How to create UI programmatically like "Settings UI" iPad?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, user-interface

I am developing iPad app and want to create settings UI like iPad have with all orientation.

That is, Left is the list of settings (General, mail, Wifi,video etc) and right side detail of selected setting option. Below are the images:

[image: Portrait Mode]

[image: Landscape Mode]

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I didn't tried anything. Becoz I have no idea that how to start.

Comment: Then why don't you start by reading about the [UI Elements of iOS in the "HIG"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1).

Comment: +1 Thanks David.finally I can start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout of the settings app in the iPad is done using a [UISplitViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
[view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeig ht|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

after create **uiview** add your controls into this uiview..

Answer (score 0):

Go through UISplitViewController Class and UITableView Class

[UISplitViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009277)

[UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)